# Menu bar in a fixed position overlaps the canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a problem with menu bars in my website. I need to put the menu bars fixed for working in canvas. I have set position: fixed.

The problem is that I have others menus that sometimes I need to put visible and overlaps the canvas.

I make a small example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/NgHTN/1/

```
<div id="menus">
    <div id="hbar">Menu Bar</div>
    <div id="hbar1" style="display:none;">Menu Bar 1</div>
    <div id="hbar2" style="display:none;">Menu Bar 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="c" width="500px" height="800px">CANVAS</canvas>
</div>
```

Please click in "New Menu Bars". What is need is that when I click in "New Menu Bars" the canvas moves to bottom and when I click in "Only 1 menu", only display 1 menu and moves canvas to top, like initial...
I don't know exactly the height of all menu bars.

Is there any trick to show, hide not setting the margin size?

Please help me solve this problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you will need a javascript solution;

Working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NgHTN/4/

Basically, we will set the top css parameter after we display each block to the height of the #menus div.

First, set canvas to position : relative.

Then add handlers.

```
$("#btnNewMenu").click(function(){
    $("#hbar1").css("display","block");
    $("#hbar2").css("display","block");
    $(".container").css("top", $("#menus").height());
});

$("#btnShow").click(function(){
    $("#menus").show();
    $(".container").css("top", $("#menus").height());
});

$("#btnHide").click(function(){
    $("#menus").hide();
    $(".container").css("top", 0);
});

$("#btnOnly1").click(function(){
    $("#hbar").css("display","block");
    $("#hbar1").css("display","none");
    $("#hbar2").css("display","none");
    $(".container").css("top", $("#menus").height());
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to set canvas to position : relative, you could do the same thing by setting "margin-top" instead of "top", but you stated that you wanted an alternative method to margins for some reason.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But in the the position fixed because I need the bars in top of my project. My project have more than 5000px in height...

Comment: In that case you will need a jQuery margin/top solution. Give me a few min

Comment: Please post the working http://jsfiddle.net/
You don't have updated... Thank You.

Comment: My apologies, I fixed the link